# Failed to allocate memory for convolution redzone checking in Keras

Tags: python-3.x, tensorflow, keras, deep-learning

I have a convolution neural network. In order to train on GPU, I create a custom data generator that loads data in batches on cpu and then gives that to GPU. I use a batch size of 20000. The code is as follows:

```
    def __data_generation(self,list_IDs):
        x = np.zeros((self.batch_size,701,5),dtype=np.int64)
        y = np.zeros((self.batch_size),dtype=np.int64)
        
        for ID in range(len(list_IDs)):
            if list_IDs[ID] in self.labels:
                x[ID] = np.load(list_IDs[ID],allow_pickle=True)
                y[ID] = self.labels[list_IDs[ID]]
            
        return x,y
```

So in each epoch my input size is (20000,701,5)
My model is:

```
i1 = Input(shape=(701, 5))

c1 = Conv1D(300, kernel_size=19,activation='relu',padding='same',kernel_regularizer=keras.regularizers.l2(l2_lambda))(i1)
c1 = keras.layers.BatchNormalization()(c1)
c1 = keras.layers.Activation('relu')(c1)
c1 = keras.layers.Dropout(0.2)(c1)
c1 = keras.layers.MaxPool1D(pool_size=3)(c1)

c1 = Conv1D(200, kernel_size=11,activation='relu',padding='valid',kernel_regularizer=keras.regularizers.l2(l2_lambda))(c1)
c1 = keras.layers.BatchNormalization()(c1)
c1 = keras.layers.Activation('relu')(c1)
c1 = keras.layers.Dropout(0.2)(c1)
c1 = keras.layers.MaxPool1D(pool_size=4)(c1)

c1 = keras.layers.Flatten()(c1)

c1 = Dense(64, activation='relu', kernel_regularizer=keras.regularizers.l2(l2_lambda))(c1)
c1 = keras.layers.BatchNormalization()(c1)
c1 = keras.layers.Activation('relu')(c1)
c1 = keras.layers.Dropout(0.5)(c1)

output = Dense(1, activation='sigmoid')(c1)

model = Model([i1], [output])

model.summary()

print('compiling model')          
model.compile(optimizer='adam',
              loss='binary_crossentropy',
              metrics=['accuracy'])
```

However, when I run the model I get the following error:

> Failed to allocate memory for convolution redzone checking; skipping this check. This is benign and only means that we won't check cudnn for out-of-bounds reads and writes. This message will only be printed once.

When I run the same model with batch size 1000, it works but then the script takes a long time to finish because I have a very large dataset with 4 million samples. So how can I make sure I am exhausting gpu entirely without running into the error I've mentioned above. I've tried changing the batch size to 5000 but the problem persists. My GPU is Tesla V100-PCIE-16GB.

Comment: The result of the first convolution alone requires 16GB to store. Same again for the results of batch norm and activation. You will either need MUCH more RAM or reduce the batch size. 20000 is absurdly high for running on a single GPU.

Comment: Thanks @xdurch, can you tell how you computed the size of first convolution in bytes?

Comment: I do it like this: Number of elements is 20000*701*300 (batch size, time, channels). That should be about 4.2 billion elements. Each element takes 4 bytes in float32, so multiply by 4. Divide by 1024 three times to get KB, MB, GB. Result is 15.66GB. In standard backpropagation implementation, these activation maps need to be stored for gradient descent. You can do similar computations for the deeper layers, which should require less space due to fewer channels and the use of max pooling.

Comment: Thanks! This helped.